# Ошибка установки приложения на avd

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

В связи с появившейся нуждой начал изучать разработку под android, использую Intellij Idea Ultimate (в ней все в комплекте есть что нужно или что идет в Android Studio), все работает и инсталится ровно до тех пор пока я не пытаюсь перевести проект на java 8, когда я пишу в build.gradle 

`compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }` 
получаю сообщение что нужно использовать jack :
[image: сообщение используйте jack]

все с Jack работает нормально, но не работает Instant run, (известная проблема)

В интернетах за конец 16 - начало 17 годов нашел решение - использовать дефолтный набор инструментов, для чего там рекомендуют обновить `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` до версий `2.4.0-alpha4` и выше

после этого ошибка пропадает но при попытке запуска приложения получаю такое сообщение об ошибке:
[image: Сообщение об ошибке]
После нажатия "OK" ничего не меняется только есть сообщение об еще одной ошибке :
[image: ошибка удаления]

Может кто уже сталкивался, знает как это исправить?

P.S. удалять вручную приложение с avd пробовал - не помогает
P.S.S. удалять avd и создавать новый пробовал - не помогает
P.S.S.S. чистить и пересобирать проект gadle пробовал - не помогает
P.S.S.S.S. создавать новый пустой проект и не меняя ничего кроме минимально необходимого для java 8 (плагин и target / source compatibility) - та же ошибка

Comment: Не совсем по вопросу хочу спросить - зачем вам Java 8 на Android? Она не полностью поддерживается и только с API версии 24 (Android 7.0+), я бы остался на Java 7 (и таки остался с новым проектом для Android, который сейчас делаю), это не скажется на качестве приложения, но работать будет стабильнее.

Comment: @therainycat как то привык к 8 версии на десктопе и в веб и жалко отказываться от ее новых возможностей (относительно 1,7)

Comment: бэта версия Android Studio 3.x [поддерживает java8 без использования jack](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) и без ограничения по api, попробуйте ее. но как уже сказали,поддержка java8 в andoid [не полная](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features). Так же рекомендую обратить внимание на язык kotlin (который AS 3.x поддерживает из коробки), он даст множество новых "возможностей" и относительно java8

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, попробую, а в рамках уже установленной ide это не лечится ? (права админа для установки на не своем пк итд)

Comment: возможно EAP IDEA и использует плагин AS 3.x, надо релизы смотреть, иначе ждать, когда AS 3 выйдет из бэты и перенесут это в IDEA. по проблеме в вопросе затрудняюсь сказать, но от jack гугл отказался за неперспективностью, работы по нему больше не ведутся, баги не правятся и тд.

Comment: @pavlofff версия Android Support плагина - Version: 10.2.3 [скрин](http://i.piccy.info/i9/f0052ec37d3322771e20fd92ca007dc7/1504655901/60384/1177287/Snymok_ekrana_25_.png)

Comment: @pavlofff gradle версией 3.3+ плагин который com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0 ? пробовал его 2.4+ 2.5+ - безрезультатно

Comment: плагин [версии 3.0.0 beta4](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) от 3 AS, он использует gradle 4

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, но увы `Gradle sync failed: This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum
  Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)`    придется все таки ставить параллельно AS 3